# Sharing mp3 files on the net with the simplicity of Dropbox

Tags: automation, dropbox, joomla

I have a website (Joomla), where I wish to share MP3 files. Every week, we have a new MP3 recording.
I would like to make the weekly upload as simple as possible. 
The typical hassle looks like this:

1. Log in to Joomla as admin
2. Upload the new MP3 file
3. Edit the download page: adding the link referring to the new file.

This would work, but it is certainly not simple. I am thinking of having the entire solution automated, somehow like Dropbox does. **Just copy the new MP3 to a dedicated folder, and let the system do all the upload and link creation hassle.** Unfortunately, Dropbox does not allow website visitors to browse/list the content of its  public folder.

Important: the MP3-s do not need to be copied to OUR Joomla site. Any public site is fine from Dropbox till Skydrive or anywhere else. But I wish to have some automated solution of having links appearing within our Joomla site.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a Dropbox folder on your machine
2. Make the folder public
3. Write a script enumerating the public URLs of the files in that folder ([REST API reference](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api))
4. Have the script results on your sites - people will click the links and would actually download from Dropbox

I believe you need to register to have access to the Dropbox API - but it's free.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specifically use Dropbox, then why not use one of [the extensions for Joomla that connect to your Dropbox account](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/cloud-storage).

Answer (score 0):

Building off Traveling Tech Guy's solution, [DropboxIndex](http://code.google.com/p/kosciak-misc/wiki/DropboxIndex) is a Python script that generates an HTML file with links to the files in a Dropbox public folder.

What the workflow would then be:

1. Put the MP3s in the Public folder
2. Run the script to regenerate the HTML file

In Joomla, you would then link to the index.html file that it generates.